# Keep track over every action performed by users on the system (CRUD operations)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, audit, audit-logging

I'm working on a application where client need to keep track on every action performed by users so they can know which users made some mistake and which kind of mistake and when it does. I'm doing some research on this and found [Loggable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md) and [Entity Audit](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit) but neither convinces me at all so, did yours did something like this in the past? Have any suggestion around this? I'll like to do this outside PostgreSQL for example in a noSQL DB like MongoDB or any supported by Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Comment: Do you need to keep track on a user basis? Or just a general log of when issues occur?

Comment: What is the difference between them? What I need is to track the action performed by a user at system level, let's said something like User has changed Order status, User has printed the Order and so on, that kind of log is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Loggable` will log any changes (insert, updates, removes) that you decide to log (it also allows for rollback due to it actually versioning your changes). I'm not sure about `EntityAudit` as I have never used it but I assume they are similar.

As for logging print out and what not then you should probably use some events that a listener could listen to and then update logs from that.